# How can I get rid of this firefox console warning?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I get this css warning on the browser (firefox) console when I open my web page:

> Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. materialize.min.css:13:42355
>
> Elements matching selector: .file-field input[type="file"]
>
> NodeList [ input#galleryFile ]

Here is snippet about the gallery file:

```
  <div id="modal-gallery" class="modal grey">
        <div class="modal-content center-align">
          <h4>Gallery</h4><br/>
          <div class="gallery"></div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="file-field input-field">
                <div class="btn blue">
                  <span>Upload Photo</span>
                  <input id="galleryFile" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I do not like seeing errors or warnings on the browser console when inspecting my web pages. If there is any one that could suggest what should I do to clear this warning, please now is the time I wish to hear your input.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you import big libraries like this, you're bound to get some warnings.  Ignore it.  It has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’. Error in parsing value for ‘filter’. Declaration dropped.` materialize.min.css:13:42355`

Elements matching selector: .file-field input[type="file"]

NodeList [ input#galleryFile ]
```

As the error says is not from your HTML5 file. The error comes more in to the code itself.

`materialize.min.css:13:42355`, nothing to worry about.